# Real story of Hampnie Hambart?

Tags: sunday-without-god

In *Sunday Without God*, Ai's father takes his name from a story about a toy that continues to move for eternity after its spring breaks.

Is there an actual story on Hampnie Hambart that was pulled as a reference into the anime? Or is this simply character background information?

Comment: I'm pretty sure they made the story up specifically for the anime; notice how the toy moving after its spring stops is a metaphor for how Ai's father doesn't die. A quick Google search turns up absolutely nothing not related to Sunday Without God.

Comment: That's what I thought, however I asked just in case there was anything.